# Uninstalled Python 3.3

Tags: 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 a few days back, dual-booting with Windows. I mainly use Python 2.7, so I installed that (I downloaded the .tar.gz file from python.org), but for some reason (`_tkinter could not be found`), I could not use Tkinter. I tried various ways of installed Tkinter/Tk, but they didn't work, so I thought I should uninstall it and reinstall it. In the terminal, this was my command: `sudo apt-get remove python2.7`. However, this removed Python 3.3, which came pre-installed. Thus, one by one the applications stopped working and I had to restart my computer. Now, I can log in to Ubuntu but nothing appears on the desktop. No dock, nothing. Not much of a problem, since I still have Windows 7 installed.

I also booted Ubuntu with advanced-options and then used the root to try to reinstall Python 3.3 (`sudo apt-get install python3.3`) but it said I have the latest version installed already.

However, I just checked using a partition manager (DiskInternals Linux Reader), and Python 3.3 is still there, at /usr/lib/python3.3. 
Could this be another problem then? If so, how can I fix it?

I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu because when I first installed it, it reset Windows (located on my C drive, my D drive remained unaffected) back to its defaults, and I had to reinstall all of my programs.

Comment: if you could provide us the list of pkg's uninstalled then more we can solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.3
```

that will fix your issue.

Comment: I can't access the terminal directly; like I said nothing shows up once I log in. I can use the root terminal by booting Ubuntu with advanced options... Would that work as well?

Comment: I will update my answer with how to open terminal with KB

Comment: I have tried that before, and it did not do anything. I just tried now, and still nothing happens when I tried Ctrl+Alt+T.

Comment: yup! type ctrl+alt+f1 and then login there. then you can continue.

Comment: I finally got into the command line and logged in, then used 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.3', then after exiting and restarting my computer, the problem of a blank desktop persists.

Comment: seems to be Unity broken , now issue will be new. try this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thank you! As far as I can tell, this seems to have fixed it (the dock appears and most applications seem to work).

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND you are welcome. Keep updating your system , so you can get what you have lost.